# Python simple for loop logic (index out of range)

Tags: python, for-loop, wxpython, logic, wxwidgets

I'm getting the error "tuple index out of range" when my DeleteButton function is called. I'm trying to delete multiple objects from a list at once. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my logic?

```
def DeleteButton(self,event):
    sel = self.task_list.GetSelections()       

    length = len(sel)       

    for item in range (0, length):
        index = sel[item]
        self.task_list.Delete(index)
        sel = self.task_list.GetSelections()
        length = len(sel)
```

Comment: You are modifying your `sel` inside your `loop`. That might be giving you a problem.

Comment: doh! i realized that I shouldnt be deleting whatever the index is, but i should always be deleting the first item in the loop until there are no more to delete. Solved my own problem, but thank you all for looking at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never having had any experience with wxPython, I'm coming at this a little naive, but from what I can discern from the documentation, wouldn't the following make much more sense?

```
def DeleteButton(self, event):
    for id in self.task_list.GetSelections():
        self.task_list.Delete(id)
```

It seems like `GetSelections` returns a list if ids of selected items, so why the extra complexity in your example?

Comment: This is much more "pythonic" than using a while loop with index access.  I think this answer is the most readable version, although you could go with a 1-line version if you really want :) `map(self.task_list.Delete, self.task_list.GetSelections())`

Comment: These are definitely both simpler ways of putting it. However, I'm having an issue with both of these examples. When I click "delete task," it only deletes the first item in the selection..

Comment: Are you sure GetSelections() is returning more than one id?  If you modify Demian Brecht's example to print the id before calling Delete, what does it output?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `while` loop with a manually incremented counter rather than trying to reset the top of the range each iteration of the `for` loop, mainly because that can't work.

```
range(0, length)
```

creates a `list`, which is then iterated over by the `for` loop, and can be though of as immutable for the duration of the loop, so trying to reset `length` won't do what you think it will.  To illustrate the problem more explicitly, here's some equivalent code:

```
i = 5
l = range(0, i) # l now set to list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for v in l:
    i = v # this has no effect, as l is already instantiated and separate from i
```

Edit:

To respond to your comment, here's a `while` loop that should fix the `for` loop issue (though not other issues that likely exist in your code).

```
sel = self.task_list.GetSelections()
i = 0
while i < len(sel):
    index = sel[i]
    self.task_list.Delete(index)
    sel = self.task_list.GetSelections()
    i += 1
```

Comment: would you mind showing me an example of a good while loop? these things trip me up